# Tychonoff's theorem vs closed ball

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

If Tychonoff's theorem is true, why closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not compact?

The theorem says that if $X_i$ is compact, for every $i\in I$, so $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ is compact. Then take $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and we have $\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[-1,1]_i$ in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is not compact. But, what??

Comment: The closed ball is not homeomorphic to the product of closed intervals if the product is infinite...

Comment: I think the main point is that Tychonoff's theorem refers to the product topology, which is different from many topologies that one typically considers on infinite dimensional spaces.

Comment: That should be $\Bbb{R}^\infty$ in the first line, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An infinite product of copies of $[-1,1]$, say, is indeed compact in the *product* topology, but a Banach space topology is *not* like a product topology; the "closest" we can get to that kind of a topology in an infinite-dimensional Banach space is the so-called weak-* topology (which is not metrisable most of the time, so quite unlike the norm topology, which of course is), and there we can prove the [Banach-Alaoglu theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem) which shows that the ball in that topology *is* compact and in which the Tychonoff theorem is a key ingredient of the proof...

Comment: Thanks, I still don't arrive in capther of weak-* topology (actually is my final paper's object hehe).

Answer (score 0):

$\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}}[-1,1]$ is indeed compact under product topology. I believe you misunderstand the structure of a closed ball, that is a closed ball $B_{d}(x, \epsilon)$ is defined to be the set $\{y: d(x,y) \leqslant \epsilon\}$ for some $\epsilon$, not $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}}[-1,1]$ as you claimed. And the set $B_{d}(x, \epsilon)$ is clearly not compact.

**Proof** Let $\gamma < \epsilon$. Consider the set $B = \{ (\gamma,0,0,...), (0,\gamma,0,...), (0,0,\gamma,0,...) \} \subset B_{d}(x, \epsilon)$ is closed in $B_{d}(x, \epsilon)$ and has discrete topology, therefore it can not has limit point in $B_{d}(x, \epsilon)$. This contradicts with the face that compactness implies limit point compactness.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's right (the proof). But, its mean that $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}}[-1,1]\neq B(0,1)$?

Comment: @EliasKemperFilho Yes. For example, the point $x=\{1 - 1,  1-\frac{1}{2}, 1 - \frac{1}{3},... \} \in \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}}[-1,1]$, but since $d(x,0) = 1$, hence $x \notin B(0,1)$.